Ошибка на загрузочном экране в тг игре
Присутсвует ошибка на загрузочном экране.
HTTP Responce  Header "Content-type" configured incorrectly on the server for file 
Build/EJCOIN.wasm,should be "application/wasm" 
Startup time perfomance will suffer

Игра сделана на Юнити билд в WebGL закиул на хостинг на рег.ру все работает ,но когда Запускаешь бота горит вот это шляпа пару секунд.НЕ могу понять  чем проблема.
